# Search if a value exist in Service-Based Database in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have made a **textbox** for user to enter id and I want to see if it exists in my table or not

```
HotelDatabaseDataContext db = new HotelDatabaseDataContext();//database 

customer_id = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);//value from textbox
var selected = from x in db.Customers
               where x.Id == customer_id//selecting value from database
               select x; 

/* I want to see if "selected" is null or not and want to store it's value in another variable */
if(selected.id==null)
{
    int _id = selected.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a linq query is an `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`. If you want to check that you have that record use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var item = selected.FirstOrDefault();
if(item != null)  
{
    int id = item.id;
}

//or:
int id = selected.FirstOrDefault()?.id;
```

Comment: @AftabIshfaq - it is an int, just used `var` for snippet. See update